# DHIS 2.30 is displaying some icons and buttons with corrupted characters

Tags: dhis2, character-set

I have installed DHIS2 2.30 on tomcat 9 with PostgreSQL. I have a problem with the display.

For example, when I go to 'Maintenance', the button for 'Add' and 'List' are not showing right. They are showing corrupted characters.  The same thing is happening on that page with the 'Metadata group editor' icon at the top right.

When I go to the demo site, the display is correct.  How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: I've never tried running DHIS, but this type of problem is usually a character set issue.  It could be a problem with the meta tags in your template.  It could be a setting in your content management system.  It could be configuration problem with your database.   I doubt that this text is coming from the DB, so I would start with your front end.   Most CMS (including DHIS, I believe) use UTF-8 as the character set.  If you are trying to use anything else anywhere, or even trying to rely on defaults, that could be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Tomcat 8.5 and it solved the problem.

Comment: It looks like you posted this answer with a separate account from the account with which you asked the question.   You may have done so by logging in with email vs social media in the two cases.   You should try merging them: [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or OpenID / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous)

Comment: I have the same issue and have installed Tomcat 8.5 but still have the same issue.